# Laravel query two models which are not related and return fields from both

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 models:

1. Property (fields: prop_id, a, b, c)
2. OfferDemandmatch (fields: prop_id d, e, f)

Both models have the **prop_id** column which can must used to join both models.
I have a blade view where I do a `foreach` for matchs collection and I need to have inside each collection item, the fields from Property and OfferDemandmatch model.

This is the code for Match collection sent to balde view

```
class OfferdemandsmatchsController extends Controller
{
    public function index ($id) {
        $matchs = OfferDemand::findOrFail($id)->offerdemandsmatchs;
        return view('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.index', compact('matchs'));

    }
}
```

This is the code in blade view

```
<div class="row">
  @foreach($matchs as $match)
      @component('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.matchbox')
      @endcomponent
  @endforeach
</div>
```

I will need to use Property and Match fields in each `foreach` iteration in blade view. So, my collection items must contain fields: prop_id, a, b, c, d, e, f

How can I achieve this?

Regards

Comment: You will need to provide more information, such as model code and some more explanation of expected response. Why are you not using a relation between the models?

Comment: By the Last paragraph, he wants a full join from 2 tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helloo, im writing in the phone and cant explaint very well neither format the answer.

Go to laravel docs and search how to do a crossjoin. This will join both databases.

```
$data = DB::table('tbl_property')->crossJoin('tbl_offerdemand')->get();
```

Edit 1: normal join on prop_id

```
$data = DB::table('tbl_properties')->join('tbl_OfferDemandmatch', 'tbl_properties.prop_id', '=',  'tbl_offerdemand.prop_id') ->select() ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @hmrneves !

I reviewed teh documentation and crossjoin combines all values. What I need is to join both models with prop_id value and return fields from both models.

Comment: Hi, you can do both ways. I update the answer to give example about join with prop_id. Regards

Comment: Thanks @hmrneves !

I made this work with the following approach:


`public function index ($id) {
        $matchs = DB::table('offerdemandsmatchs')
                ->join('properties', 'offerdemandsmatchs.prop_id', '=', 'properties.prop_id')
                ->where('offerdemandsmatchs.offerdemand_id', '=', $id)
                ->select('properties.*', 'offerdemandsmatchs.*')
                ->get();
         dd($matchs);
        return view('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.index', compact('matchs'));

    }
`

Comment: Hi, you dont need the select atributs. Use select() only since you need everything.

Comment: No problem. I think you dont need where, since you filter by prop_id. But you need to test it.hapoy coding!